# How to show currency symbol and price in separate elements?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, price, catalog-price-rules

I want to show currency symbol and amount in separate html elements such as:
**BD18.00**

into this:

```
<span>BD</span><span>18.00</span>
```

is it achievable?

Comment: Heyy.. 
Did you get anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterfa‌​ce'); 
$currencyCode = $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); 
$currency = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFact‌​ory')->create()->loa‌​d($currencyCode); 

echo "<span>{$currency->getCurrencySymbol()}</span><span>{$product->getPrice()}</span>"; 
?>
```

Comment: I can show in this way, but I want it to behave like default price like changing custom option, will change price as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the price format by change theme files.

```
\app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml
```

Just replace or comment

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
```

and add the following snippet

```
<span class="av-new-price"><?= $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode() ?></span>
    <span class="av-amount"><?php echo number_format($block->getDisplayValue(),2) ?></span>
```

If this file not in your directory just overrides.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the currency symbol and currency code in your template file:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
$currencyCode = $storeManager->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$currencyFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory');
$currency = $currencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCode);
$currencySymbol = $currency->getCurrencySymbol();
$productPrice = $_product->getPrice();
$productFinalPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
echo "<span class='cur-code'>".$currencyCode."</span>"; // prints currency code of your current store. E.g. 'USD' OR 'EUR' OR 'GBP' OR 'INR' etc..
echo "<span class='cur-symbol'>".$currencySymbol."</span>"; // prints currency symbol of your current store. E.g. '$' OR '€' OR '£' OR '₹' etc..
echo "<span class='prod-price'>".$productPrice."</span>";// prints product's price value.
echo "<span class='final-price'>".$productFinalPrice ."</span>";// prints value of product's final price.
?>
```

This is a tested code and will print the values as per your current store or as per the active currency switcher.

Hope this will help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this below code

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$currencysymbol = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

$currency = $currencysymbol->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency();